# Execution of joined table valued UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Situation:
I have a main-table *ORDER* with 10,000 rows and a related detail-table *ORDERPOSITIONS* with 100,000 rows.

For the *ORDERPOSITIONS* table there is a table valued UDF "udf_SumPos" doing something like this:

```
INSERT INTO @table
SELECT t1.order,
       sum(t2.price) sumPrice
FROM   ORDER t1
       JOIN ORDERPOSITIONS t2
         ON t1.order = t2.order
GROUP  BY t1.order
```

QUESTION:

If I use following SQL-statement:

```
SELECT t1.order,
       t2.sumPrice
FROM   ORDER t1
       JOIN udf_SumPos() t2
         ON t1.order = t2.order
WHERE  t1.order = 'MyOrderNumber'
```

Will the SQL-Server execute the udf  "udf_SumPos()" for the whole table ORDERPOSITIONS or just for the record with ORDER = '**MyOrderNumber**'?

(for some reasons I can't use CROSS APPLY or an inline scalar UDF)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will do it for the whole of the `ORDERPOSITIONS` table.

SQL Server doesn't even attempt to optimise multi statement TVFs in the context of the overall query and won't push predicates into it as you are hoping.

You would need to use a view or inline TVF to allow this overall optimisation.

Or alter the multi statement TVF to accept a parameter telling it the rows to filter.

Comment: So you mean if i use a view (instead of the udf) like this:

create view [dbo].[viewSumPos] as
select orderNo,(select sum(price) from ORDERPOSITIONS where orderNo = t1.orderNo) as sumPos from ORDER t1

I can join this view and it will only be executed for the rows in ORDERPOSITIONS according to the where-Condition?

Comment: @Reggie - In principle, yes. The view gets inlined into the query and the query is optimised as a whole. So predicates can get pushed into the references to Orders and OrderDetails contained in the view. You can check the execution plan to see if this happens.